# output not that expected using argument list spread

Tags: php, parameter-passing

output not that expected using argument list spread

I expected that each passed variable should come out in bold. but it happens that it is not working.

https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/b14Y

```
<?php
class TestCLass{
    public function outputbolt($var,$bold)
    {
        if($bold){
            return '<b>'.$var.'</b>';
        }else{
            return $var;
        }
    }

    public function testFunc(...$var)
    {
        return implode('<br>', array_map([$this, 'outputbolt'],
            $var,[true]));
    }
}

$runTest = new TestCLass;

$var1='TextBold';
$var2='TextBold';

echo $runTest->testFunc($var1, $var2);
```

output expected:

```html
<b>TextBold</b><br>
<b>TextBold</b>
```

Current output :

```html
<b>TextBold</b>TextBold<br>
```

Comment: `outputbolt` doesn't return anything so `array_map` produces an array with no values. Your `echo` statements execute at the time `array_map` evaluates each entry

Comment: zorry i have update the class XD

Comment: Seems to work as expected ~ https://3v4l.org/jaOit. If you were wanting to second arg to be made bold, you should pass `[true, true]` as the second array in `array_map`

Comment: not only bold first argument not the second.... i have set a second argument fixed [true]... only work with first...

Comment: I suggest you read the manual page for [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.array-map.php) ~ _"Usually when using two or more arrays, they should be of equal length because the callback function is applied in parallel to the corresponding elements. **If the arrays are of unequal length, shorter ones will be extended with empty elements to match the length of the longest.**"_

Comment: Instead of `[true]`, try `array_fill(0, count($var), true)`

Comment: @Phil but, it has no logic, I am supposed to pass the arguments with the spread `(...$var)` so that I can analyze each argument dynamically ... I cannot put `[true, true]` because I don't know the number of variables that were passed .. .why each `"$var"` variable only needed to be passed once ...

Comment: yes work with `array_fill(0, count($var), true)`

Comment: @Phil you Do you consider that this programming is object oriented? Yes or no; Can you improve to do it that way?

Comment: It's not particularly. You just have a utility class that might as well be static. You could just as easily stick a couple of functions in a `namespace` and achieve the same result without any classes. But if you have no _"objects"_, you can't just make something OOP

Comment: @Phil thank you friend, your response is very kind and well documented; thanks for editing the question too; You should put the answer so that you get a couple of points.